# Unable to Change Log Levels - Winter '16

Tags: apex, developer-console, debugging, platform-bug

Working in sandbox with Winter '16 and when I try to change the log levels the page stalls
[image]

I've checked the known issues list and haven't gotten any results. Has anyone run to this? Any workarounds to change the log levels?

Things I'm trying which so far haven't worked

- creating a new workspace
- refreshing the developer console

Comment: I have had the same issue. I noticed that it eventually loaded when I looked back hours later.  I have been changing the log levels in the debug logs setup and will try the trace flags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was able to get the page to load again by clearing out the `TraceFlag` table

1. `select id from TraceFlag` in dev console query editor (enable 'Use Tooling API')
2. Select all rows, click 'Delete Row' button